# Copy column cells value from 1 sheet to another sheet rows

Tags: excel-formula

I am not sure whether can I ask Excel related questions in stackoverflow. This is my first time using excel and I have no idea how to start or what is the search keyword to my answers. My explanation sucks so I will use screenshots instead below :

I have a few products like this in the Product Sheet

[image]

I want those products to be display like this in Customer Sheet

[image]

Is it possible to do it? I am currently using google sheet to do this. Thanks in advance guys! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl + Alt + V To paste which will open a dialog , Click on the transpose checkbox ( At the bottom right of dialog ) and click On Ok.

[Paste Special Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU5Tz.png)

Use a formula

You can use it as a Formula. For example you have values from A1 To A10 in Sheet1. You Can apply this formula in a cell in Sheet2 =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:A10)

List In Sheet1
[image]
As columns in Sheet2 using formula in B2 Cell As =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:A10)
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you! But what I wanted is I am not doing the copy paste manually. Everytime I update a new product in the "Products" sheet, it will automatically update in "Customers" sheet in transpose manner. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can use it as a Formula. For example you have values from A1 To A10 in Sheet1. You Can apply this formula in a cell in Sheet2 =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:A10)